# QML import item from sibling folder

Tags: qt, qml, qt-creator

Suppose I have the following structure in my `qml.qrc`

```
<RCC>
<qresource prefix="/">
    <file>main.qml</file>
    <file>Style.qml</file>
</qresource>
<qresource prefix="/components">
    <file>Test.qml</file>
</qresource>
```

main.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.5
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.0
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0
import "components"
Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    Test {
        color: "red"
    }
}
```

Test.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import ".."


Rectangle {
    width: Style.test * 200
    height: 200
}
```

Style.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.0
pragma Singleton

QtObject {

    property real test: 1.0
}
```

I have for some time tried to import `Style.qml` from `Test.qml` with `import "../"` but I keep getting `ReferenceError: Style is not defined`

I know the import statement is the cause for this and I have tried a few different variants of what "might" work but the docs are lacking on this and I am stuck. Help appreciated.

Comment: I think the problem is in my use of singleton, I didn't know what to search for but this seems to be a common issue and the way to import singletons is outlined in http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-modules-qmldir.html

Comment: Ok, thanks for the update! I think the reason this doesn't work for you is the use of a singleton type. It looks like the problem you're hitting is that you need a qmldir file for Style -- add a file 'qmldir' containing 'singleton Style 1.0 Style.qml' in the same directory as Style.qml (& add it to your qrc in the same location), and your example seems to work then. I'm not yet sure if this is a bug or correct behaviour, I'll try dig deeper.

Comment: *Update* It seems this is a design limitation at the moment, I've opened a bug to either try fix or attempt to better document it at https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-58238.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the following code, I have no errors, and see the expected visual result. I'd suggest including a more complete example, if you can't spot your problem from this working sample. Note that all paths I give here are relative from the "root" project directory (so e.g. main.cpp is a file in the "root", components/Test.qml is located in a "components" subdirectory):

main.cpp:

```
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QGuiApplication>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
    QQmlApplicationEngine qAppEngine(QUrl("qrc:/main.qml"));
    return app.exec();
}
```

main.qml

```
import "components"

Test {

}
```

components/Test.qml:

```
import ".."

Style {

}
```

Style.qml:

```
import QtQuick 2.6
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 500
    height: 500
    color: "red"
}
```

---

Built with the following:

test.pro:

```
QT += quick qml
RESOURCES += test.qrc
SOURCES += main.cpp
```

test.qrc:

```
<!DOCTYPE RCC><RCC version="1.0">
<qresource>
    <file>main.qml</file>
    <file>Style.qml</file>
    <file>components/Test.qml</file>
</qresource>
</RCC>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I tried but it doesn't work with my setup. I have a more complete example above. I work with Qt from QtCreator, there is no subfolder but for compartmentalization I have ordered files by prefix in my project.

Comment: See my comments on your original question. I provided you with an answer of sorts there; thanks for the update!